# How can a big table be treated as a database?

Tags: pattern-matching, data-structures

I often work with big tables that I want to treat kind of like a database. Here's an example table.

```
theTable = {
 {"id","color","size","flavor"},
 {1,"blue",5,"cherry"},
 {2,"green",5,"piquant"},
 {3,"blue",20,"peppermint"}
}
```

In a database I would ask

```
SELECT * FROM `theTable` WHERE `color` = 'blue' AND `size` > 10
```

and get effectively

```
{{3, "blue", 20, "peppermint"}}
```

in response. In *Mathematica*, I need to determine the "column number" for `color` and `size`, then use `Cases` with `And` to do the same thing.

```
Cases[theTable[[2 ;;]], a_ /; And[a[[2]] == "blue", a[[3]] > 10]]
```

This is operationally much clumsier than the database way. Unfortunately setting up a database for every such table is too much extra work, particularly since I want the data to end up in mma anyway.

How can this approach be improved? Specifically, how can I more easily use the column names directly, instead of their part numbers? And how can I avoid the ugly `a_/;f[a]` pattern?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787901/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica/4788373#4788373), and those linked to it, particularly [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240943/data-table-manipulation-in-mathematica-step-2?lq=1)? Those can be a starting point.

Comment: I had not seen those. That is a neat solution and I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: If you went with DatabaseLink you don't have to create one database for each table, but one table for each table. Not soo much work

Comment: @Rojo I did not test it for hsqldb, which is in-memory database and therefore should be fast, but since all database access in DatabaseLink goes through JDBC and J/Link, I would think that for large tables and when the result of the query is also a large collection of rows, the performance hit may be quite noticable.

Comment: You know that `Extract[theTable, Position[theTable, {_, "blue", x_ /; x > 10, _}]]` works, right?

Comment: Just to be clear, in your real application you don't actually know what column number colour and size are? If you do know the actual structure of your table then why not `Cases[theTable, {_, "blue", x_ /; x > 10, _}]`?

Comment: @J.M. and Mike, the real table sometimes has hundreds of columns. Today's has 36, which is still too many to build the pattern like that, don't you agree?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens that was important information for us ;)

Comment: Consider, then, `ReplacePart[ConstantArray[_, 4], Thread[Flatten[Position[{"id", "color", "size", "flavor"}, #] & /@ {"color", "size"}] -> {"blue", x_ /; x > 10}]]`.

Comment: @Argento: "that was important information for us" - which you should have included to begin with.

Comment: @J.M. I think that one of the biggest conveniences of SQL tables is that you get a symbolic (string) handle for each column, which is its name. It is invariant under permutations of columns and addition / removal of columns, so SQL queries are maintainable. The solutions I linked to solve this problem by automatically generating a pure function used in the `Select` query by using the table itself, so require a minimal effort from the user. I think, you are suggesting something similar but based on `Cases`-`Position`.

Comment: @Leonid, yes something like that. :) I haven't seen your SO answer before; thanks for that!

Comment: @J.M. No problem :-). I was thinking of extending those answers into a tiny framework emulating basic SQL stuff, but did not yet find the time to sit down and do it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that would be a useful package.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, I tend to think so too. Since the simplest set of operations is probably not hard to implement, I will think about it. One thing I was concerned about was efficient inserts. Also, if I want to support indexes, things will get more complex. This is one of these problems where it is very easy to keep asking a little more and more and then suddenly open a can of worms :-). I think it is the anticipation of this that prevented    me from actually doing this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yes it could easily balloon into something large. Reflecting on this a bit more, for larger tables for any user that is familiar with basic SQL queries it is probably easier to use a database -- this is what they are for -- and use `DatabaseLink`.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, I agree. So, I would rather have an in-memory production-quality SQL database integrated into Mathematica via LibraryLink with a well-designed Mathematica-side API (perhaps the same as DatabaseLink), than rolling out something in the top-level Mathematica which would be only of a very limited value. This was actually another reason that I did not go there.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and Mike, is there a way to have a local database without installing a local MySQL server?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens Well, hsqldb seems to be such a database. It comes with Mathematica I think.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens as Leonid mentioned Mma comes bundled with a database. The documentation runs through some usage examples (I have never used hsqldb myself other than in these examples). Coincidentally I was looking at this a couple of days ago because it appears to be included in Player Pro as well -- which could be useful for building apps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A way of getting around the `a_/;test[a]` syntax is to write out the tests in string form, and use replace to insert the values. For this to work you need to build rules from your table. Here is a simple implementation:

```
 SetAttributes[queryCriteria, HoldAll]
 queryCriteria[theTable_, query_] := Function[{entry}, 
 Unevaluated[query] /. (Rule @@@ Transpose[{theTable[[1]], entry}]), HoldAll]

 Select[theTable, queryCriteria[theTable, "color" == "blue" && "size" > 10]]
```

Personally I would prefer not having to give `theTable` as an argument to the query function constructor, since conceptually you shouldn't need a table to define a query, however it's needed during the construction because you have the field names listed in the first row. A way to nicely work around this is to consider a query an indpependent entitiy, which doesn't use the table until it's used in Select. This can be defined by setting an Upvalue pattern for Select, to resemble your included example, I use `where` as a name for the query:

```
 SetAttributes[where, HoldAll]
 Select[table_, where[query_]] ^:= Select[table, queryCriteria[table, query]]
```

So that the query can be written:

```
 Select[theTable, where["color" == "blue" && "size" > 10]]
```

This is all just ways of doing a similar thing with different syntax however. I would expect that performance issues become more important with big Databases.

Answer (score 13):

Don't reinvent the wheel: If you need a database you should be aware of the SQLite access readily built into Mathematica, though unfortunately undocumented:

```
db = Database`OpenDatabase[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "mma-temp-db.sqlite"}]];

Database`QueryDatabase[db, 
    "CREATE TABLE stuff(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,color TEXT,size REAL,flavor TEXT)"
];

Database`QueryDatabase[db, "BEGIN"];

Scan[
  Database`QueryDatabase[db, 
    ToString@StringForm[
      "INSERT into stuff(color,size,flavor) VALUES ('`1`',`2`,'`3`')",
      Sequence @@ #
  ]] &,
  theTable[[2 ;; -1, 2 ;; 4]]
];

Database`QueryDatabase[db, "END"];

Database`QueryDatabase[db,"SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE color = 'blue' AND size > 10"]

Database`CloseDatabase[db]
```

and in case you are more into speed than persistency:

```
Database`OpenDatabase[":memory:"]
```

for details just look for documentation about sqlite, there is tons of good documentation around for it...

**EDIT**: as murta mentioned in his comment it is also possible to make use of SQLite with the officially supported and documented `` DatabaseLink` ``. In version 10 a corresponding driver is included, for earlier versions a SQLite JDBC-driver has to be installed manually. As far as I can tell using the `` Database`* `` functions is a very lightweight approach most probably making direct use of the sqlite libraries while DatabaseLink` makes use of Java/JLink/JDBC which is kind of heavyweight but of course also has its advantages. Also from murta is the above example using DatabaseLink:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite",$TemporaryDirectory<>"testBase.sqlite"]];
SQLExecute[conn,"CREATE TABLE stuff(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,color TEXT,size REAL,flavor TEXT)"];
SQLInsert[conn,"stuff",{"color","size","flavor"},theTable[[2;;-1,2;;4]]];
SQLExecute[conn,"SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE color = 'blue' AND size > 10"]
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
```

For in memory version use: `conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite(Memory)","jdbc:sqlite::memory:"]];`

Just for completeness: there are also drivers for HSQL included in all versions of DatabaseLink that I can remember of which provide similar functionality as SQLite, since version 10 there are also drivers for H2 and Derby included which also claim similar functionality.

**EDIT**
since version 11.1 the `` Database` `` functions have been removed. So for any version newer than 11.0 one has to use the `` DatabaseLink` `` approach, but as they come with the SQLite driver you still can access SQLite databases in those versions out of the box.

Comment: Executing the first command: ``db = Database`OpenDatabase[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "mma-temp-db.sqlite"}]];`` I get ``Database`Database::liberror: A required library could not be located or opened.`` in MMA V10.0.2

Comment: You can do the same with documented commands, with: ``Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite",$TemporaryDirectory<>"testBase.sqlite"]];``

Comment: interesting, which OS are you on? I've used that in several MMA versions (example was written and tested with V10.0.2) on Windows and never had problems, but I remember to have seen complaints of others...

Comment: @murta: Yes, since version 10 I think there is a SQLite driver for DatabaseLink predefined, I'll make an addition about it. It probably is also worth mentioning that the undocumented access is very lightweight compared to what DatabaseLink does, but often using the documented stuff is still a better idea...

Comment: yes, I just confirmed. Worked in Windows but not in Mac OSX 10.10.2. Do you know if there is some memory version for JDBC? I would be great.

Comment: @murta: I think that you just have to give :memory: or file::memory: where you usually would give the path to the sqlite file in the connect string to open an in memory database, but I have not tried if that works with DatabaseLink. I'd really be interested to learn what goes wrong on OSX with Database`OpenDatabase. AFAIK sqlite as such is available and working on macs, so it probably is just a matter of adjusting/correcting some library pathes...

Comment: just tried `conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite", ":memory:"]]` and that seems to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20910/discussion-between-murta-and-albert-retey).

Comment: Using "::memory::" just create a SQLite file called "//memory//" in your current `DirectoryStack[]` not memory.

Answer (score 7):

I had forgot about this question, or the answer linked by @Leonid, or @jVincent's etc, and last week I was under the same "need".

I'll just post what I used since it's no extra work, in case it still helps someone.

Speed wasn't a concern, so I have no clue how much time this wastes

```
LabeledMatrix[cs_, mat_][cols : {__String}, funQ_] := 
    LabeledMatrix[cs, mat][cols, funQ, cols];

Normal[LabeledMatrix[_, mat_, ___]] ^:= mat

(lm : LabeledMatrix[cs_, mat_?MatrixQ])[cols : {__String}, funQ_, showCols : {___String}] :=
    Extract[mat[[All, label2Position[lm, showCols]]], 
      Position[LabeledMatrix[cs, mat][cols], {i___} /; funQ[i], {1}]];

LabeledMatrix[cs_, mat_?MatrixQ][cols : {__String}, All] := 
    LabeledMatrix[cs, mat][cols];
(lm : LabeledMatrix[cs_, mat_?MatrixQ])[cols : {__String}] := 
    mat[[All, label2Position[lm, cols]]];

SetAttributes[label2Position, Listable];
label2Position[LabeledMatrix[cols_List, ___], lab_] := 
    First@Flatten@Position[cols, lab, {1}, 1];
```

There's basically no error checking, formatting rules, etc.

**Usage**

`LabeledMatrix` is a wrapper. It takes, as a first argument, the names of the columns, and as a second, the data matrix.

```
lm = LabeledMatrix[
   {"ID", "Person", "Age"},
   {{4, "Peter", 23}, {5, "Mary", 33}, {55, "John", 23}}];
```

Say you want the "Person" and "Age", column

```
lm[{"Person", "Age"}]

(* {{"Peter", 23}, {"Mary", 33}, {"John", 23}} *)
```

The first argument, (unless you use the 3 argument form), is a list of the columns you want as output.

If you give a second argument, then that second argument is a predicate function to filter rows. The arguments taken by that function are those supplied in the first argument. Example

```
lm[{"Age", "ID"}, #2 > #1 &]

(* {{23, 55}} *)
```

If you supply a third argument, it's the list of columns returned. The first argument still works as the input to the predicate. So, say you want the IDs of the people aged under 30

```
lm[{"Age"}, # < 30 &, {"ID"}]

(* {{4}, {55}} *)
```

A second argument of `All` is the same as nothing. `Normal` gives the data matrix. `First`, or some other convenience function you want to create, the names of the columns.

Answer (score 7):

1. Keep your data in external .csv files. Data is stored/queried in/from "tables" in a db anyway.
2. query=ReadList["!grep ...", String]
3. Process query, use ToExpression where appropriate, etc.

This has the following advantages:

- you don't actually *keep* your data in the kernel, you keep it in files, outside of the M system. That's where data storage SHOULD be: outside of the kernel. You shouldn't use the kernel for data storage, only for data processing.
- now the kernel will contain and process only your extraction / query result / result set. MUCH more memory-efficient. You shouldn't have in the kernel what you're not interested in anyway.
- grep and egrep are extremely fast. You're actually outsourcing the query to operating system speed.
- you don't need the overhead of a real d/b system (CPU, memory, installation, drive space, etc.) You only consume the drive space needed for your .csv files

What I've described above is actually how I *do* store large data amounts of data that I want to be available for queries. I don't consider this a workaround, it's a solution. Instead of installing a d/b application, I ALWAYS ask if I can simply do my tables (which I'd have to set up in a d/b system anyway) as well-designed .csv files (conforming to certain d/b standards, such as normalization, etc.), and then use the speed of grep, o/s methods, and ReadList["!grep ...",...], and then string-based processing and possible type conversions. Should be extremely hard to beat that speed, you don't need external d/b applications, you don't have external links (as you may be aware of, M's DatabaseLink package uses JLink internally), and you have additional flexibilities with this approach. You could, for example, save the .csv files from spreadsheet programs or other generators, and you can zip them when you want to archive them (text files can be zipped down to 7%), and you could even include zip/unzip steps in your M program to "set up" your d/b. A collection of properly formatted .csv files *is* actually a relational database! A simple d/b is nothing but a collection of well-organized tables, so you can do it yourself with text files (I recommend .csv).

Comment: I'm going to be dealing with large files and databases soon. It's been ten years since you wrote this. Have you discovered new methods to do this? Or is this still the optimal method? Are you dealing with other files besides CSVs now?

Comment: I still recommend to use such Linux command line tools, and to submit from ReadList (or sometimes Read) to the command line, rather than reading in everything into the M kernel. I still use mostly .csv, although the important thing here is to use text files, that can also be .xml or .json for non-rectangular formats, or others.

Comment: That's what I've gathered as well. Any interesting command line tools? perhaps there's specific mathematica integration? I have text, pdfs, graphs, images, videos, xml, json, and databases to play with. I'm just thinking out loud here: dealing with a lot of data is even more important today; and now we have Apple Silicon and unified computer architectures that can access media engines and neural engines and other specialized engines. I'm sure the people working behind the scenes of wolfram language have a different view of what is possible with the code and language. Lots of potential.

Comment: I have found grep, egrep, curl, sed the most useful Linux command line tools for "pre-extracting" data that is then read into the M kernel. ReadList["!command",...], don't forget the !. You can even submit entire perl programs to the command with the -e option, such as ReadList["!perl -e <whatever>",...], although I acknowledge that nowadays people would probably prefer python over perl. ReadList["!python <option to submit code to command line><whatever>",...]. Also awk. You could write very effective extractors in awk, perl, phython and then read in just the extraction.

Comment: You can also use Java's REPL, the jshell, from the command line, and with the - option specify that you don't want interactivity, this is like the -e option for perl: ReadList["!echo \"System.out.println(\\\"Hello World\\\");\" | jshell -"]. I also find the -n option for perl very useful when used with -e, because it gives you the diamond operator without specifying the outer while loop. So with perl -e -n you get to parse the raw text data, line by line, in a diamond operator, without while loop. I find that incredibly useful, but I acknowledge perl is considered outdated nowadays.

Comment: Cool! I've never used perl (found the command line options you mentioned and some more: -e -E -n -p -i) or jscript. I could probably do something with python. I'll stick with unix commands at first to see the extent of what is possible with that. Aside from python, perl, jscript, and unix commands, what else have you been using? Anything with databases? Also, was there something that was just not possible or practical to do through wolfram language?

Comment: I had only mentioned perl just in case you need something that can not be done with simple Linux commands. I find that grep, curl, sed cover everything I need. After all, this post is about big tables / databases, and a relational database is simply: a collection of tables, so you don't need much more than these. And earlier you had also asked about .pdf, and there are several Linux tools for that too to extract text or tabular structures from .pdfs.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for responding.

Comment: I found some very interesting pdf related tools but not quite what I was expecting. What are some of the linux pdf tools you've been using? I'm on a mac with apple silicon btw.

Comment: Don't know anything about Macs, and that will never change, I won't even touch them with pincers. On Linux, for command line-based extraction from .pdf you could start with pdftotext. Start testing it from the command line with something like pdftotext mydoc.pdf - | grep mysearchstring. Then read that in with ReadList, as above, ReadList["!pdftotext mydoc.pdf - | grep mysearchstring",String]. You might prefer a workflow that converts to html first, and then parse the html, there is pdftohtml: ReadList["!pdftohtml whatever",String]

Comment: lol Pincers may be sufficient, no? I have a linux system now as well. pdftotext is running on the mac. The -xml Option is also very useful. pdffonts and the rest of popper are great. Are there other useful tools that come to mind?

Comment: For tables treated as databases, usually grep, egrep, sed do it for me. I submit a lot of Linux command line tools from M and then read back results with ReadList["!whatever",String], mostly because now I can harness M's string manipulation functions that would be much more tedious to manage from the Linux command line (shell scripts, aliases, etc.). For video editing I use ffmpeg a lot, which is what most video editing software use under the hood anyway. Most video editing software is basically just GUI-based configurations for ffmpeg, for example stuff like ...

Comment: ... ffmpeg -ss xx:xx:xx -i inputfile.mp4 -ss yy:yy:yy -t zz:zz:zz -c copy outputfile.mp4, where zz:zz:zz is a *difference*! So to add/subtract 60-based numbers I prefer to use M to generate the proper zz:zz:zz. And if properly configured, you can use ffmpeg with a GPU, making this very powerful. But all that has nothing to do anymore with the original question, using tables as databases.

Comment: True. To answer the original question, you could now use 
Query[Select[#color === "blue" && #size > 10 &]]@theNewTable
or something to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

This is my way. I'm used to name my columns as:

```
cId=1;cColor=2;cSize=3;cFlavor=4;
```

I append c because it's easy to use with the autocomplete, and prevent variables mix.
And instead of cases, I prefer to use select as below:

```
r=Select[Rest@theTable, #[[cColor]] == "blue" && #[[cSize]] > 10 &]
```

If you want to take just some columns you can make for example:

```
r[[All,{cID,cColor}]]
```

Sometimes I have a lot os columns, so is boring to make the first step so I created this function that is in my tool bag:

```
sequenceVarList[list_] := Module[{varList},
    varList = StringReplace[list, {"_" -> "", " " -> ""}];
    Clear@@varList // Quiet;
    MapIndexed[(Evaluate[Symbol[#1]] = #2[[1]]) &, varList];
    TableForm[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, varList]]
]
```

So I can use it as:

```
sequenceVarList[{"cId","cColor","cSize","cFlavor"}]
```

and the first step is done easily.

I think that the big advantage of this solution is that you can use your column names in another calculations like `GatherBy`, `SortBy` and so on.

**Update**

If you are dealing with many tables, you can use the function sequenceVarList as:

```
Unprotect[Dot];
SetAttributes[Dot, HoldAll];
Protect[Dot];

mrtSeqVarList[varList_,symbol_Symbol] := Module[{},
    Clear[UpValues[symbol]];
    MapIndexed[(symbol/:symbol.#1=First@#2)&, varList];
]
```

So now you can do:

```
sequenceVarList[{cId,cColor,cSize,cFlavor},tab1]
r=Select[Rest@theTable, #[[tab1.cColor]] == "blue" && #[[tab1.cSize]] > 10 &]
```