# Plotting data in a weird format

Tags: list-manipulation, data, filtering

I have a lot of data on the following form:

```
data = {{param1,param2,param3,param4,{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...,{xn,yn}}},...}
```

The first variables in each sublist are parameters which were used to generate the data and for each there are only finitely many, i.e. `param1` is in the set `{1,2,3,4}` and `param2` in the set `{0,0.25,0.5}`. Each possible param sequence is guaranteed to appear exactly once.

Now I would like to create all plots where a couple (or arbitrarily many) of the parameters are fixed but the other ones can vary. For example, one plot would have `param1` to be `1` and `param2` to be `0.5` then the corresponding `Plot` would vary `param3` and `param4` over their possible values.

Is it possible to do this with relatively little code?

Edit: Here is some data if you want to practice:

```
data = {{0.05,0.25,2,0.05,{{10,1.81095078464},{20,4.67233914533},{30,7.08803699724},{40,12.2604831338},{50,4.4765112617},{60,30.4472408052},{70,13.9643317682},{80,41.2579927871},{90,11.960557746}}}
,{0.05,0.25,2,0.1,{{10,2.43799671091},{20,6.61987906477},{30,0.0668059190229},{40,2.7061070004},{50,18.8102895497},{60,24.4730064793},{70,20.2747124961},{80,74.8539284102},{90,47.2172814344}}}
,{0.05,0.25,2,0.15,{{10,2.67074811192},{20,15.9521439491},{30,3.54972604159},{40,13.1682228406},{50,23.6066621641},{60,12.4390170784},{70,46.0070233365},{80,38.0116375085},{90,12.0705695205}}}
,{0.05,0.25,3,0.05,{{10,3.1269953325},{20,15.6996942029},{30,24.1145670018},{40,36.0334138554},{50,41.1150906489},{60,31.4063841784},{70,34.4001494185},{80,9.52491909762},{90,15.5320891272}}}
,{0.05,0.25,3,0.1,{{10,9.6198670177},{20,1.68271939508},{30,14.4069805301},{40,32.0147092546},{50,26.7042711284},{60,47.7967863197},{70,46.7059123396},{80,57.809041849},{90,84.4256784391}}}
,{0.05,0.25,3,0.15,{{10,3.62785141167},{20,7.48741493046},{30,2.08245578621},{40,36.2518798094},{50,20.0541864045},{60,38.5706584591},{70,42.2491352509},{80,33.8688792853},{90,12.5218627351}}}
,{0.05,0.25,4,0.05,{{10,6.113253503},{20,3.34466308592},{30,22.8994502487},{40,27.8256812834},{50,42.3128480576},{60,11.8814975842},{70,23.6489403538},{80,67.2170848449},{90,64.7381753617}}}
,{0.05,0.25,4,0.1,{{10,6.63675406908},{20,14.2655858882},{30,2.16789822064},{40,34.6305949789},{50,31.7812530609},{60,45.0207978304},{70,29.9999048737},{80,66.9741618718},{90,55.0452401763}}}
,{0.05,0.25,4,0.15,{{10,6.90255549999},{20,3.9885321713},{30,26.7487549741},{40,17.9087260172},{50,15.897872199},{60,9.29221539717},{70,59.9905412021},{80,51.2029208226},{90,43.2240798207}}}
,{0.05,0.25,5,0.05,{{10,2.03521621274},{20,10.6802820552},{30,22.7668370169},{40,17.4842532703},{50,33.8885022742},{60,53.1974918374},{70,60.2751976503},{80,40.7192672242},{90,83.5475720189}}}
,{0.05,0.25,5,0.1,{{10,7.67431501913},{20,1.95859099835},{30,23.3519464193},{40,13.8993657827},{50,31.6415181272},{60,23.1976359038},{70,35.0005300883},{80,17.0312839157},{90,57.0400103646}}}
,{0.05,0.25,5,0.15,{{10,5.06555796312},{20,10.9204321376},{30,21.8069692381},{40,19.5772020736},{50,11.3270822542},{60,4.81298507075},{70,59.7538646808},{80,66.1476668838},{90,73.1291546231}}}
,{0.05,0.5,2,0.05,{{10,4.64402575054},{20,11.0700265682},{30,13.5807209068},{40,17.4950974568},{50,10.358793839},{60,15.8021221186},{70,63.1214522278},{80,57.8308798847},{90,22.5414408889}}}
,{0.05,0.5,2,0.1,{{10,4.38798903726},{20,3.70039642682},{30,25.1663321348},{40,5.08534158813},{50,30.2269860186},{60,12.9107480373},{70,10.2495871724},{80,41.7860842547},{90,21.3519476486}}}
,{0.05,0.5,2,0.15,{{10,6.77220056497},{20,7.38600235623},{30,11.5745943742},{40,30.5829816576},{50,38.589061723},{60,57.6488293351},{70,1.26057229892},{80,5.9267804496},{90,82.6704015928}}}
,{0.05,0.5,3,0.05,{{10,3.32034254713},{20,10.971486433},{30,0.363147390123},{40,37.65329461},{50,15.949633583},{60,21.8418741365},{70,28.3562497933},{80,71.7087071989},{90,79.5554695131}}}
,{0.05,0.5,3,0.1,{{10,1.58954955321},{20,3.76237825847},{30,17.5550842398},{40,29.2109934963},{50,6.49252024706},{60,51.8137399056},{70,41.9546186462},{80,24.1401496171},{90,84.1640682329}}}
,{0.05,0.5,3,0.15,{{10,9.01150441341},{20,10.9523361655},{30,20.6533901253},{40,24.3713540557},{50,8.20484429104},{60,1.16388638136},{70,2.7717770797},{80,36.0311528516},{90,79.6148650441}}}
,{0.05,0.5,4,0.05,{{10,2.64807693809},{20,17.4186809674},{30,11.0988927114},{40,12.9430380703},{50,20.1267053993},{60,56.2647281546},{70,69.2811052248},{80,27.6645633652},{90,85.1136096421}}}
,{0.05,0.5,4,0.1,{{10,6.02663873848},{20,2.63294032126},{30,7.74879650203},{40,8.27484945215},{50,5.95510226084},{60,52.6154234102},{70,12.511545849},{80,78.8192910206},{90,12.3488606088}}}
,{0.05,0.5,4,0.15,{{10,8.25216926779},{20,7.60388967899},{30,1.0533107346},{40,2.21081169594},{50,35.7020132845},{60,57.911449844},{70,17.5890809513},{80,15.1115721942},{90,1.02639298919}}}
,{0.05,0.5,5,0.05,{{10,8.49277943149},{20,2.51406868421},{30,11.4011785147},{40,39.4308578521},{50,39.8307541943},{60,35.5969342248},{70,62.2928703256},{80,71.5575481117},{90,61.6565219289}}}
,{0.05,0.5,5,0.1,{{10,3.425448449},{20,10.3597097543},{30,6.19100953018},{40,10.4540143146},{50,23.2857082412},{60,17.3599512427},{70,28.7492345283},{80,35.9268076613},{90,23.5710386153}}}
,{0.05,0.5,5,0.15,{{10,2.87691906629},{20,15.5942388106},{30,27.7675182329},{40,26.9156263637},{50,30.0860121249},{60,46.5691600184},{70,59.5923947398},{80,13.3664590053},{90,46.9926862072}}}
,{0.05,0.75,2,0.05,{{10,2.33118591118},{20,0.171302391205},{30,3.8162801126},{40,38.1028271195},{50,15.9557228127},{60,10.9717594589},{70,50.4761540499},{80,34.2194752184},{90,57.3320890909}}}
,{0.05,0.75,2,0.1,{{10,9.21187915809},{20,15.931228085},{30,13.2347014451},{40,2.09075850626},{50,35.9255672695},{60,33.953217097},{70,16.9449485001},{80,3.7436362842},{90,35.5772239774}}}
,{0.05,0.75,2,0.15,{{10,0.791065400588},{20,14.0143142872},{30,3.37600328092},{40,22.3812487398},{50,21.1693240081},{60,19.7087594303},{70,68.1887031769},{80,38.0093505188},{90,37.7895850656}}}
,{0.05,0.75,3,0.05,{{10,9.31810727853},{20,9.76215342921},{30,7.76683101607},{40,35.3384426319},{50,44.4717515812},{60,53.5710585193},{70,45.4840193583},{80,59.5407627578},{90,60.4710222303}}}
,{0.05,0.75,3,0.1,{{10,2.53659798611},{20,4.70704669175},{30,18.2959346871},{40,35.9224308806},{50,36.5480039338},{60,43.4640708957},{70,7.24722453278},{80,40.943093786},{90,81.9694316569}}}
,{0.05,0.75,3,0.15,{{10,0.100105878083},{20,15.6660867132},{30,23.5308070875},{40,8.19490108256},{50,6.02445100435},{60,28.6216840496},{70,69.2893512352},{80,3.7744156909},{90,80.9475721672}}}
,{0.05,0.75,4,0.05,{{10,8.0933835982},{20,18.9656256251},{30,18.4700662413},{40,1.67540094072},{50,12.411938782},{60,1.63616227618},{70,12.593678348},{80,70.6808044911},{90,53.8566296064}}}
,{0.05,0.75,4,0.1,{{10,3.19835596466},{20,19.0476174241},{30,1.58525644896},{40,4.57246061776},{50,41.0673261923},{60,30.72857255},{70,11.9372932092},{80,76.8378358811},{90,23.608111421}}}
,{0.05,0.75,4,0.15,{{10,6.6446636599},{20,0.295275665136},{30,11.6826665238},{40,16.6603278505},{50,42.0122936272},{60,51.8210661871},{70,37.1211762546},{80,28.8305779696},{90,15.4410237106}}}
,{0.05,0.75,5,0.05,{{10,4.44734165144},{20,6.66893577711},{30,3.55054836325},{40,9.4767095531},{50,25.7843768065},{60,24.2743878743},{70,34.2370917884},{80,34.9507738144},{90,83.5111434619}}}
,{0.05,0.75,5,0.1,{{10,7.84586864359},{20,12.0472863816},{30,27.395358028},{40,7.26350803368},{50,2.6064473865},{60,51.377539089},{70,31.276369458},{80,59.1499919813},{90,31.8353206328}}}
,{0.05,0.75,5,0.15,{{10,2.20956347811},{20,11.078484084},{30,5.07233531175},{40,38.1356170453},{50,29.6534616181},{60,6.38250659035},{70,62.4726098813},{80,33.6021622135},{90,29.8045456453}}}
,{0.05,1,2,0.05,{{10,6.77714943938},{20,5.657718189},{30,19.0493303978},{40,39.636743496},{50,34.5096155839},{60,13.9300761353},{70,45.9834142675},{80,4.64884310707},{90,59.6849298315}}}
,{0.05,1,2,0.1,{{10,3.86505813154},{20,10.0886018939},{30,6.65846439181},{40,26.1224551281},{50,30.9014736954},{60,11.4155036781},{70,33.0291680043},{80,74.6509229773},{90,36.9492872204}}}
,{0.05,1,2,0.15,{{10,1.99654946557},{20,16.2049557761},{30,26.1363569323},{40,38.7372287427},{50,40.2025346552},{60,39.8858065844},{70,10.3023904166},{80,41.8886418279},{90,70.9094529273}}}
,{0.05,1,3,0.05,{{10,2.34518030674},{20,12.2556329339},{30,3.05566675163},{40,26.8300477228},{50,30.6367983486},{60,19.4331000773},{70,62.9975381973},{80,73.4322628917},{90,39.1957337766}}}
,{0.05,1,3,0.1,{{10,7.68796282248},{20,15.9096854918},{30,4.54025818601},{40,7.45388052723},{50,12.457354139},{60,24.3015045943},{70,50.2688106134},{80,36.1148253991},{90,67.9233729094}}}
,{0.05,1,3,0.15,{{10,4.65218387794},{20,16.8386602868},{30,25.5930142898},{40,7.82172541215},{50,1.29242214896},{60,21.5544155961},{70,31.7440802727},{80,19.2507862987},{90,4.07000801216}}}
,{0.05,1,4,0.05,{{10,0.69101208094},{20,9.34880796351},{30,7.17856203574},{40,30.112388804},{50,40.8619565867},{60,9.43604345999},{70,69.6804647491},{80,32.8742327742},{90,36.8468278409}}}
,{0.05,1,4,0.1,{{10,7.52710101478},{20,10.4920352043},{30,15.4111870748},{40,35.6243877241},{50,3.94992669146},{60,49.8266439283},{70,69.5140218785},{80,70.5337864009},{90,85.3876987564}}}
,{0.05,1,4,0.15,{{10,3.62234353787},{20,14.2397062922},{30,25.1356228484},{40,37.8715362786},{50,23.6113234196},{60,48.1540335361},{70,10.2338938212},{80,34.8127725764},{90,54.6251642429}}}
,{0.05,1,5,0.05,{{10,3.42309751666},{20,12.8828592654},{30,5.04947596019},{40,37.9218907866},{50,33.1506882433},{60,37.6953472861},{70,5.73178257281},{80,7.03749358685},{90,79.2393944507}}}
,{0.05,1,5,0.1,{{10,3.77053553619},{20,7.42357221292},{30,19.8494673301},{40,27.7478936358},{50,46.6825595981},{60,12.1764819866},{70,57.2046605066},{80,65.2407822409},{90,33.7164233635}}}
,{0.05,1,5,0.15,{{10,6.49191956291},{20,5.32890967287},{30,13.1398913983},{40,25.8084558834},{50,44.0679908978},{60,16.0657787413},{70,65.846463301},{80,5.709476188},{90,50.5077277368}}}
,{0.1,0.25,2,0.05,{{10,8.1805131568},{20,13.3839416884},{30,5.35535429554},{40,31.1637561463},{50,29.2251514633},{60,56.7644536173},{70,28.6419959787},{80,77.7369839641},{90,64.1029710405}}}
,{0.1,0.25,2,0.1,{{10,4.00140666299},{20,10.8863043703},{30,2.81582596423},{40,27.4965991947},{50,25.0337108129},{60,12.1412568651},{70,21.2241844654},{80,55.4861523882},{90,84.2383928999}}}
,{0.1,0.25,2,0.15,{{10,6.53764557883},{20,3.1053903961},{30,11.515699156},{40,25.6597655992},{50,44.0127890186},{60,46.0691492929},{70,56.2843023454},{80,43.1056203069},{90,28.4124452184}}}
,{0.1,0.25,3,0.05,{{10,0.721470639814},{20,14.5078204964},{30,17.2573095333},{40,36.1034897775},{50,40.4045204395},{60,55.1468706076},{70,56.6263585656},{80,51.9798227207},{90,14.6412003494}}}
,{0.1,0.25,3,0.1,{{10,2.87370884284},{20,4.56253572796},{30,14.6945541145},{40,13.9546874469},{50,7.4818924749},{60,16.5381563607},{70,20.3566470069},{80,38.6153112546},{90,48.0178060833}}}
,{0.1,0.25,3,0.15,{{10,2.83875203825},{20,15.0609608907},{30,17.5240166232},{40,22.4293300139},{50,21.6102852167},{60,9.15004256886},{70,45.6354523511},{80,69.5680089543},{90,5.71728103804}}}
,{0.1,0.25,4,0.05,{{10,4.46646009433},{20,5.7320048815},{30,11.4016738341},{40,8.83523265091},{50,16.4847370272},{60,36.8009395286},{70,24.5999040271},{80,14.1650741968},{90,8.02876977497}}}
,{0.1,0.25,4,0.1,{{10,0.488156430383},{20,9.73307404131},{30,0.597418004153},{40,23.0552672427},{50,16.2087532724},{60,34.43009287},{70,27.3554342695},{80,70.311017112},{90,28.0188921989}}}
,{0.1,0.25,4,0.15,{{10,5.3461674224},{20,2.91528771185},{30,18.9550685617},{40,17.5601781976},{50,35.342927073},{60,3.18860635682},{70,52.5782031356},{80,11.2419622939},{90,79.0487883136}}}
,{0.1,0.25,5,0.05,{{10,3.24319494011},{20,9.20282886188},{30,15.2186717481},{40,23.3891524884},{50,36.1335727272},{60,38.6728479249},{70,41.9240629723},{80,22.7397645521},{90,9.30747274433}}}
,{0.1,0.25,5,0.1,{{10,7.59497995474},{20,0.405926294602},{30,11.8418092773},{40,34.5152511797},{50,33.1815145209},{60,18.2661886311},{70,25.4418955824},{80,31.9778916064},{90,73.9786748628}}}
,{0.1,0.25,5,0.15,{{10,6.12961088543},{20,19.9331364341},{30,18.2545077545},{40,15.1198651774},{50,26.0912471551},{60,35.1203226514},{70,12.2285551291},{80,72.1932144614},{90,53.0386701391}}}
,{0.1,0.5,2,0.05,{{10,7.59488953517},{20,11.2978335861},{30,22.5064570351},{40,2.35265743589},{50,0.908253825134},{60,56.5655545397},{70,27.0860153547},{80,78.0129191571},{90,49.7715169565}}}
,{0.1,0.5,2,0.1,{{10,1.43860542157},{20,16.0605769084},{30,4.63441645706},{40,21.4207950368},{50,7.68008769367},{60,34.8078464101},{70,26.8410066037},{80,31.5708973783},{90,32.8848746975}}}
,{0.1,0.5,2,0.15,{{10,8.39514333251},{20,10.0341828507},{30,9.38010187697},{40,34.4526749456},{50,5.80913020794},{60,51.8092369073},{70,49.3295337536},{80,55.6237692935},{90,61.8200747267}}}
,{0.1,0.5,3,0.05,{{10,9.38641922534},{20,17.9040760206},{30,0.25707206566},{40,34.093764649},{50,34.5677933731},{60,19.2397646578},{70,33.2670768537},{80,47.890923252},{90,34.3797445311}}}
,{0.1,0.5,3,0.1,{{10,4.00465844105},{20,15.5385282854},{30,18.6173588469},{40,22.6123989951},{50,1.62301944438},{60,18.1239726264},{70,17.3044858704},{80,22.0666086744},{90,11.5168991949}}}
,{0.1,0.5,3,0.15,{{10,2.56845586386},{20,13.0816651606},{30,17.8228500021},{40,37.6102328305},{50,8.51102447018},{60,7.89016813299},{70,41.0452165717},{80,58.5787413693},{90,18.2308463676}}}
,{0.1,0.5,4,0.05,{{10,2.49727084491},{20,3.56416194578},{30,6.27724685884},{40,6.72849195117},{50,43.2802722534},{60,26.4631951187},{70,10.1557053085},{80,11.5753957119},{90,59.7621806738}}}
,{0.1,0.5,4,0.1,{{10,7.60259722645},{20,6.0118465907},{30,28.0628724627},{40,31.3206046138},{50,21.9790486839},{60,16.6828749185},{70,58.8901143246},{80,64.3715017101},{90,6.40250308925}}}
,{0.1,0.5,4,0.15,{{10,9.37837560535},{20,9.30356878331},{30,5.68459387165},{40,28.3961060974},{50,29.9119490477},{60,33.244421553},{70,43.4853149932},{80,62.8169391547},{90,35.0986227335}}}
,{0.1,0.5,5,0.05,{{10,5.46777855196},{20,0.307003624332},{30,5.57189679082},{40,8.58812353128},{50,12.2046576077},{60,25.5712910446},{70,69.7711454398},{80,60.98627112},{90,8.24922668557}}}
,{0.1,0.5,5,0.1,{{10,0.621904144918},{20,4.84235895254},{30,3.81862601241},{40,21.0939034156},{50,38.4562570489},{60,57.3622032991},{70,34.6407205654},{80,8.55277344038},{90,0.777217632246}}}
,{0.1,0.5,5,0.15,{{10,5.7173069971},{20,4.10396300275},{30,24.0751334673},{40,6.41106554954},{50,45.6411938905},{60,0.464834918316},{70,65.728589585},{80,32.7945564693},{90,24.0931788427}}}
,{0.1,0.75,2,0.05,{{10,8.9647599673},{20,13.8216677501},{30,20.6509238656},{40,20.365515982},{50,37.3223482332},{60,24.2570338722},{70,62.0867170638},{80,59.4777900977},{90,72.215984611}}}
,{0.1,0.75,2,0.1,{{10,8.42005651213},{20,17.4999589292},{30,3.18182290422},{40,31.8665894313},{50,48.8812894167},{60,10.6751908611},{70,46.9148403878},{80,0.417086397777},{90,89.4324954751}}}
,{0.1,0.75,2,0.15,{{10,6.44725231886},{20,10.9257419595},{30,21.3480009383},{40,11.2193148168},{50,36.2819546524},{60,25.1980712824},{70,56.4458146677},{80,10.108865306},{90,26.3041268147}}}
,{0.1,0.75,3,0.05,{{10,4.76687201456},{20,2.78989303629},{30,3.67872578585},{40,24.1374000229},{50,3.13458262944},{60,22.2339463736},{70,17.0706266227},{80,0.46493078169},{90,65.959591258}}}
,{0.1,0.75,3,0.1,{{10,6.50453054541},{20,7.66629452689},{30,2.18985081258},{40,21.4462060735},{50,16.3647659138},{60,38.586050839},{70,11.6351479006},{80,0.84607270655},{90,7.05753337902}}}
,{0.1,0.75,3,0.15,{{10,4.0610082593},{20,15.1629496968},{30,4.6376315212},{40,15.0197681633},{50,3.42353231587},{60,11.2098760836},{70,59.3599278468},{80,46.2574383148},{90,30.0227121794}}}
,{0.1,0.75,4,0.05,{{10,6.79334000709},{20,3.64370415789},{30,2.92337375089},{40,3.71977381894},{50,10.2636864607},{60,46.1272101065},{70,25.8935720849},{80,53.4883066026},{90,58.2896223886}}}
,{0.1,0.75,4,0.1,{{10,1.81625327454},{20,9.1493886242},{30,21.6836267294},{40,38.482437867},{50,46.4318396042},{60,10.765721794},{70,56.0258192172},{80,42.3598501793},{90,74.5022119774}}}
,{0.1,0.75,4,0.15,{{10,4.91841545877},{20,5.57999390777},{30,17.2716487067},{40,8.32139860991},{50,27.118256565},{60,5.46594819281},{70,47.1932186526},{80,7.43005621694},{90,50.9875832678}}}
,{0.1,0.75,5,0.05,{{10,4.84480861517},{20,9.89888074325},{30,23.719083084},{40,21.6634899375},{50,6.24732011313},{60,14.7097765113},{70,49.185263844},{80,21.8097321312},{90,5.75514824834}}}
,{0.1,0.75,5,0.1,{{10,8.72037052137},{20,16.9280326386},{30,19.6704245917},{40,2.2125274622},{50,15.3600385385},{60,10.9563720553},{70,52.0689616958},{80,73.5710362191},{90,26.8088678002}}}
,{0.1,0.75,5,0.15,{{10,9.95186325046},{20,16.3136582824},{30,11.6979744236},{40,0.390557619389},{50,29.5577821847},{60,34.2375392989},{70,9.22324351563},{80,21.4867656467},{90,82.804390641}}}
,{0.1,1,2,0.05,{{10,8.01947891818},{20,19.0030754209},{30,29.2534122496},{40,39.6517823844},{50,18.2692954953},{60,23.1307961294},{70,68.2725326916},{80,12.3784992514},{90,71.1986069198}}}
,{0.1,1,2,0.1,{{10,9.23874572535},{20,4.85901936625},{30,18.0100639081},{40,32.7408384003},{50,47.8114580113},{60,23.6229427755},{70,43.2051735821},{80,52.5047783624},{90,56.6538206218}}}
,{0.1,1,2,0.15,{{10,2.18668510165},{20,6.47091257525},{30,3.69963204643},{40,28.982935417},{50,42.8761749312},{60,49.1153650022},{70,57.9429307973},{80,11.2986463003},{90,51.7788844007}}}
,{0.1,1,3,0.05,{{10,6.77783614674},{20,2.81269851199},{30,9.45030617237},{40,33.65108013},{50,10.1677736682},{60,46.9784275808},{70,60.9172862729},{80,70.7104862139},{90,74.9261280021}}}
,{0.1,1,3,0.1,{{10,4.65720840751},{20,10.1327336666},{30,1.90984732965},{40,32.3275755173},{50,0.435936583222},{60,45.8175975866},{70,47.4533679588},{80,35.9151943427},{90,69.9355750233}}}
,{0.1,1,3,0.15,{{10,3.14620186579},{20,17.5287557021},{30,4.38044924704},{40,11.2242619732},{50,26.7538648845},{60,19.625339826},{70,26.9681460657},{80,26.551959502},{90,67.3403824536}}}
,{0.1,1,4,0.05,{{10,2.45905372009},{20,6.80734076308},{30,9.49468578494},{40,2.91440008801},{50,7.43992468803},{60,31.3034293358},{70,58.6334534046},{80,58.3966360905},{90,4.24386984986}}}
,{0.1,1,4,0.1,{{10,8.70808261833},{20,11.2891542398},{30,1.13024382079},{40,10.8438009489},{50,11.7378548573},{60,3.80709658481},{70,39.4049530881},{80,29.3675429242},{90,88.7765618262}}}
,{0.1,1,4,0.15,{{10,2.8564967445},{20,2.55970309021},{30,1.82376394264},{40,17.356910227},{50,30.8140739479},{60,2.08020674412},{70,17.6770250168},{80,18.1465135984},{90,44.7002502179}}}
,{0.1,1,5,0.05,{{10,7.50890691437},{20,1.25860156777},{30,11.413242993},{40,32.2701127332},{50,45.6851952997},{60,32.7826212573},{70,53.6919597832},{80,20.1546284974},{90,56.0546054759}}}
,{0.1,1,5,0.1,{{10,1.55501998388},{20,13.6101858787},{30,26.3039157732},{40,3.71133073671},{50,2.75002246892},{60,42.4083005206},{70,30.1913313307},{80,79.9464593415},{90,10.8913239805}}}
,{0.1,1,5,0.15,{{10,8.40347456801},{20,2.71774550648},{30,2.54605906123},{40,9.53561142156},{50,1.33916929469},{60,53.5867377515},{70,7.09177186215},{80,0.0771498793567},{90,70.7764408365}}}
,{0.15,0.25,2,0.05,{{10,4.68889441753},{20,7.96328611892},{30,4.01655719657},{40,21.4895894832},{50,7.21124318842},{60,16.4955182638},{70,11.2999917365},{80,66.9551195168},{90,14.8138192007}}}
,{0.15,0.25,2,0.1,{{10,0.517993279265},{20,16.066755246},{30,27.2075729967},{40,16.761246485},{50,31.8746102425},{60,55.129175232},{70,12.0329711581},{80,66.9226678716},{90,4.91759471141}}}
,{0.15,0.25,2,0.15,{{10,1.60563632198},{20,0.808022096937},{30,9.40626770679},{40,18.732981883},{50,39.7743614053},{60,28.8355704351},{70,1.12319650437},{80,78.7319637689},{90,68.9857589052}}}
,{0.15,0.25,3,0.05,{{10,2.89225746093},{20,1.97981361428},{30,3.02844548018},{40,33.2608527643},{50,47.0988291149},{60,17.5358894285},{70,50.1779410412},{80,56.1287857996},{90,84.3115488225}}}
,{0.15,0.25,3,0.1,{{10,3.08374136533},{20,5.36159511848},{30,8.82159447513},{40,31.2989966591},{50,42.6818470719},{60,50.9076958336},{70,67.1340546208},{80,59.2816112466},{90,46.6317583343}}}
,{0.15,0.25,3,0.15,{{10,5.00073654068},{20,4.86978545236},{30,25.6100602708},{40,26.3444063013},{50,44.2071496109},{60,48.1289504872},{70,28.3840618896},{80,48.5504799168},{90,81.3278959088}}}
,{0.15,0.25,4,0.05,{{10,0.474552124823},{20,19.1813339281},{30,17.0823033268},{40,13.2763070699},{50,1.52919979435},{60,1.10918913802},{70,30.5900743464},{80,35.3862006585},{90,46.5202909192}}}
,{0.15,0.25,4,0.1,{{10,0.78502703143},{20,13.8053434159},{30,29.3308235345},{40,31.4326229529},{50,35.879561435},{60,58.6646762952},{70,7.13661589461},{80,51.9184114507},{90,12.9126119593}}}
,{0.15,0.25,4,0.15,{{10,8.03184355161},{20,14.518902875},{30,6.71186215894},{40,12.4692281207},{50,0.108964620372},{60,50.2138429107},{70,1.0027792354},{80,40.3083820936},{90,43.2726718215}}}
,{0.15,0.25,5,0.05,{{10,7.9298886513},{20,13.3568866398},{30,0.412442324174},{40,16.1925022486},{50,39.5801568193},{60,48.8022449388},{70,27.5056867849},{80,28.5742908039},{90,19.195436989}}}
,{0.15,0.25,5,0.1,{{10,3.78046217182},{20,1.73580206043},{30,9.90425096184},{40,27.0857249394},{50,18.6996113057},{60,45.6483527599},{70,35.1159743894},{80,35.018340979},{90,46.3053966847}}}
,{0.15,0.25,5,0.15,{{10,9.21442775668},{20,15.5372747147},{30,1.55404164102},{40,20.2501331773},{50,11.1655613111},{60,30.6286665029},{70,29.8099455664},{80,21.6683568949},{90,30.2897020349}}}
,{0.15,0.5,2,0.05,{{10,3.82577122405},{20,4.83654121189},{30,25.9854611943},{40,20.4281707827},{50,13.1519319846},{60,57.5224327887},{70,24.1312539624},{80,51.5561727025},{90,72.0152217532}}}
,{0.15,0.5,2,0.1,{{10,2.48104504954},{20,1.98813590853},{30,8.89383873614},{40,35.3223984111},{50,12.82167681},{60,31.446273846},{70,47.399755286},{80,16.2191878487},{90,34.3738933555}}}
,{0.15,0.5,2,0.15,{{10,0.128157214862},{20,17.7527285702},{30,1.85672988998},{40,26.3261710132},{50,35.1002730227},{60,58.6647534766},{70,29.6514416302},{80,46.4906600405},{90,50.7336191388}}}
,{0.15,0.5,3,0.05,{{10,2.42977873126},{20,11.4065972833},{30,12.2325223357},{40,7.35699143943},{50,8.98633428928},{60,27.278158577},{70,41.2520641615},{80,64.7368128489},{90,35.9381539364}}}
,{0.15,0.5,3,0.1,{{10,3.36741635439},{20,12.1881082757},{30,8.34373600407},{40,0.160955987188},{50,40.2280085569},{60,13.4140754916},{70,47.2298087306},{80,29.6386177696},{90,6.24083806263}}}
,{0.15,0.5,3,0.15,{{10,6.55567638439},{20,11.6433140143},{30,18.6784140582},{40,14.4245865566},{50,21.2774363467},{60,15.4403251852},{70,1.10025606097},{80,65.7737507532},{90,0.18892941952}}}
,{0.15,0.5,4,0.05,{{10,7.05561654667},{20,18.0497589848},{30,8.85720306598},{40,8.54153113697},{50,42.1041293159},{60,38.0016904869},{70,52.5305570507},{80,56.8090754876},{90,6.52293463126}}}
,{0.15,0.5,4,0.1,{{10,5.51963147088},{20,3.92689462016},{30,27.5315817379},{40,13.2097948115},{50,39.7504488077},{60,27.7090247267},{70,29.9366229863},{80,51.8689863754},{90,22.2191642971}}}
,{0.15,0.5,4,0.15,{{10,2.09993877734},{20,4.74432715333},{30,20.0197617606},{40,31.9687687764},{50,45.070091919},{60,37.0739879901},{70,69.6953971482},{80,25.4230410921},{90,69.1332083604}}}
,{0.15,0.5,5,0.05,{{10,1.47174285055},{20,0.903182300914},{30,22.1220288476},{40,18.7759588738},{50,23.5391522581},{60,55.8545061124},{70,20.4774424447},{80,72.7681097854},{90,82.9887709869}}}
,{0.15,0.5,5,0.1,{{10,5.86860565438},{20,2.69599657409},{30,29.130898613},{40,27.9599492333},{50,44.9737050978},{60,15.2427491707},{70,16.6220571044},{80,42.1749947539},{90,23.0712614935}}}
,{0.15,0.5,5,0.15,{{10,0.181255727823},{20,11.8249517445},{30,27.3390767274},{40,25.5378567168},{50,30.1660792917},{60,51.1927849339},{70,64.5389332287},{80,17.3648055261},{90,51.0550435759}}}
,{0.15,0.75,2,0.05,{{10,1.06885241236},{20,19.024021805},{30,25.3517895354},{40,19.4389463896},{50,19.2563846552},{60,50.7368594105},{70,24.4804335591},{80,14.3453511397},{90,69.6454232131}}}
,{0.15,0.75,2,0.1,{{10,2.25956772721},{20,13.6948578507},{30,17.2831029294},{40,34.1235921555},{50,41.5407995748},{60,33.1412241657},{70,59.6146265448},{80,28.5040782889},{90,40.5776221975}}}
,{0.15,0.75,2,0.15,{{10,2.53749757344},{20,0.288123921586},{30,4.8243612897},{40,37.0010306043},{50,48.5221744618},{60,42.8174970376},{70,20.4990141686},{80,14.5076126435},{90,36.6346479207}}}
,{0.15,0.75,3,0.05,{{10,9.73911350399},{20,7.64798812625},{30,3.61925722115},{40,24.4696971313},{50,25.3560632849},{60,9.68113791502},{70,55.6156781645},{80,10.2958863034},{90,3.05286490775}}}
,{0.15,0.75,3,0.1,{{10,7.56803652019},{20,0.694446136126},{30,7.71591826247},{40,35.7931582866},{50,16.6308566938},{60,52.4850356995},{70,24.0876693109},{80,32.5979522642},{90,84.501528695}}}
,{0.15,0.75,3,0.15,{{10,2.0362405788},{20,9.83393181455},{30,20.0356757771},{40,3.23956056258},{50,33.1014781473},{60,52.5154980365},{70,48.8534802118},{80,29.9054094687},{90,66.5593126554}}}
,{0.15,0.75,4,0.05,{{10,0.155988225256},{20,11.7463722756},{30,8.92976020155},{40,29.8324618932},{50,16.4433241006},{60,15.4707798858},{70,3.40300758945},{80,3.72019120104},{90,85.0090836153}}}
,{0.15,0.75,4,0.1,{{10,1.64927098771},{20,5.82176700112},{30,18.9650314942},{40,35.2757235514},{50,8.23596927942},{60,38.0463345268},{70,39.9998886011},{80,72.0938268453},{90,29.7621199221}}}
,{0.15,0.75,4,0.15,{{10,0.969717432483},{20,4.34388704053},{30,9.79694553734},{40,33.3790464266},{50,46.6423649711},{60,13.173827153},{70,66.3759510263},{80,38.9904506078},{90,6.81079339087}}}
,{0.15,0.75,5,0.05,{{10,0.916062192565},{20,0.115210788673},{30,24.1372059981},{40,39.5487412967},{50,12.9795407898},{60,15.9648821689},{70,37.9625631927},{80,31.6042842953},{90,21.8998030479}}}
,{0.15,0.75,5,0.1,{{10,8.84944732225},{20,5.37532065994},{30,6.79135049092},{40,34.8183261061},{50,17.5822790056},{60,15.0999688535},{70,20.1620061378},{80,28.258599764},{90,54.356428217}}}
,{0.15,0.75,5,0.15,{{10,4.13626360277},{20,1.81639177357},{30,11.8839838142},{40,11.8583126285},{50,10.2111814619},{60,35.0986063785},{70,49.1595877012},{80,47.6422749245},{90,68.2012368168}}}
,{0.15,1,2,0.05,{{10,9.14284975319},{20,0.375425289587},{30,5.80761536234},{40,28.4481976307},{50,24.4168967189},{60,33.0510582974},{70,14.1624425245},{80,2.57317188875},{90,3.06360811559}}}
,{0.15,1,2,0.1,{{10,0.258580591542},{20,8.4096503308},{30,8.42750252343},{40,36.0511175762},{50,31.3343855056},{60,50.6192782387},{70,53.0348152195},{80,2.04981438806},{90,71.8808955257}}}
,{0.15,1,2,0.15,{{10,1.3262971009},{20,2.60515019012},{30,6.82750375755},{40,29.0500371429},{50,32.4143480639},{60,42.0437825838},{70,53.44893281},{80,45.8846846944},{90,42.7881414325}}}
,{0.15,1,3,0.05,{{10,1.65546007446},{20,5.10261820825},{30,4.63732861396},{40,13.5971516901},{50,36.1429628731},{60,0.233076617445},{70,44.1208165382},{80,64.3679667518},{90,72.091892827}}}
,{0.15,1,3,0.1,{{10,0.98815666183},{20,19.5232636183},{30,12.5041815891},{40,4.75761671169},{50,26.3484261076},{60,15.9968755762},{70,4.44527972207},{80,29.5279938082},{90,10.2544330777}}}
,{0.15,1,3,0.15,{{10,9.28939712014},{20,17.809287196},{30,27.0891241084},{40,5.69167031908},{50,3.44763829902},{60,5.11336121548},{70,15.7136199463},{80,70.0789661685},{90,71.0501428088}}}
,{0.15,1,4,0.05,{{10,8.28226731203},{20,6.27905234669},{30,10.3315393165},{40,39.8157633198},{50,13.3123799553},{60,54.2748697008},{70,9.80252178201},{80,53.8320752748},{90,34.5381688841}}}
,{0.15,1,4,0.1,{{10,7.2755725719},{20,13.4831501115},{30,25.9439047268},{40,16.5083359411},{50,25.1219353484},{60,18.473011902},{70,35.7388386812},{80,61.2713787964},{90,11.3514265817}}}
,{0.15,1,4,0.15,{{10,6.48974410793},{20,8.6305872474},{30,28.8265442339},{40,6.35122734312},{50,27.5400743584},{60,55.4378616788},{70,17.4228271669},{80,15.8173313577},{90,39.0752439155}}}
,{0.15,1,5,0.05,{{10,3.23268247216},{20,13.7709591465},{30,23.3759406403},{40,22.1332707115},{50,14.3370112262},{60,55.6636959945},{70,65.8277630726},{80,74.9419416526},{90,74.190470498}}}
,{0.15,1,5,0.1,{{10,6.21455549181},{20,17.0684916775},{30,11.7651442358},{40,32.152138861},{50,17.4576146591},{60,28.2173453561},{70,51.9479490413},{80,41.2463708704},{90,13.6302645349}}}
,{0.15,1,5,0.15,{{10,3.61590425964},{20,19.7064604062},{30,7.32257426682},{40,20.1419433185},{50,17.2420775206},{60,11.5885523282},{70,57.7289284563},{80,63.9188339033},{90,3.75163366931}}}};
```

Comment: What is it precisely you want to plot?  The $(x,y)$ pairs as a line?  Or something computed from them?  If you just want to plot $(x,y)$ as a line, then are you aiming to create as many plots as there are freely variable `param` values or do you need all lines on a single plot?  Or perhaps you're looking for something computed from that line (e.g. its slope) as a function of the free `param`s?

Comment: Yes precisely, the `(x,y)` pairs as a line. I want all of the lines on a single plot (but for each 2-subset I want a separate plot). Thanks!

Comment: Please add some actual data to work with.

Comment: Ok, will do. Just a moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Keep in mind points that [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) has pointed in comments below that answer.

Big and only advantage of this method is compactness. So in this context if I had to make more reliable solution (longer) I'd rather use *database* approach.

---

You can use `Cases`. For solid solution when your data is huge and static I'd use some kind database approach probably, but have not got experience so that's all to say:)

This however, is quite short and can benefit from pattern matching possibilities:

```
ListLinePlot @ Cases[data, {0.05, 0.25, _, _, x_} :> x]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot @ Cases[data, {0.05 | 0.15, 0.25, 2, 0.1, x_} :> x]
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, short and functional :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Haffi112 It is inadvisable to use verbatim inexact numbers in patterns as done above.  Instead you should use e.g. `n_ /; n == 0.05`. Please see [(5149)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5149/121) and [(15907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907/121) for an explanation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wouldn't call it inadvisable. Just be aware of the difference between `2` and `2.` and how `MatchQ` works. But good point.

Comment: Kuba, respectfully, I don't think that's enough.  The point is that you often cannot be certain that an inexact number with have the same internal representation, therefore even if all your numbers are inexact the pattern you gave may fail to match.  One could of course `Rationalize` all values but that brings its own issues.  Restating my position: your use the pattern `{0.05, 0.25, _, _, x_}` is prone to subtle and frustrating bugs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think my edit is fair now :)

Answer (score 2):

Building from the answer to the following question
[How can a big table be treated as a database](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11151/how-can-a-big-table-be-treated-as-a-database)

```
 (*Include your data above *)
 titles = {"paramA", "paramB", "paramC", "ParamD", "Values"};
 PrependTo[data, titles];

 SetAttributes[queryCriteria, HoldAll]
 queryCriteria[theTable_, query_] := 
 Function[{entry}, 
  Unevaluated[query] /. (Rule @@@ Transpose[{theTable[[1]], entry}]), 
  HoldAll]

ListPlot[Select[data, 
   queryCriteria[data, "paramA" == 0.15 && "paramB" == 1]][[All, 5]], 
 Joined -> True]
```